# How to suppress opentelemetry java auto instrumentation for some calls

Tags: java, jdbc, quartz, open-telemetry

I use opentelemetry java agent for tracing. It provides auto instrumentation for JDBC calls. Recently I added the quartz java library. It provides a lot of traces when the quartz makes internal requests to DB.

I wonder if there is a way to suppress particular traces?
I don't want to disable auto instrumentation for all JDBC calls.

**UPDATED**

I tried `-Dotel.instrumentation.quartz.enabled=false`, but it just disables the job execution traces, but `jdbc` calls still appear.

I tried `-Dotel.javaagent.exclude-classes=`, but it's definitely hard to identify which class of quartz I need to put here to suppress the jdbc calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this behavior, we disabled auto instrumentation for quartz:

```
-Dotel.instrumentation.quartz.enabled=false
```

and provided our own extension with a sampler to identify which span is provided by quartz. More information about the extension you can find in this official example
https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/tree/main/examples/extension

Comment: if you keep the quartz instrumentation and sample those out, that decision should then propagate down and also sample out the corresponding jdbc spans

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following approach to suppress the quartz instrumentation:

```
-Dotel.instrumentation.quartz.enabled=false
```

Or using the environment variable:

```
OTEL_INSTRUMENTATION_QUARTZ_ENABLED=false
```

This would disable the quartz instrumentation, and it would avoid the over creation of spans in your case.
You can also control further using the fine-grained approach,  where you can exclude the instrumentation of specific classes with a syntax like that:

```
otel.javaagent.exclude-classes="my.package.MyClass,my.package2.*"
```

Or with the environment variable:

```
OTEL_JAVAAGENT_EXCLUDE_CLASSES="my.package.MyClass,my.package2.*"
```

Here is the whole documentation on how to suppress specific agent instrumentation: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/blob/main/docs/suppressing-instrumentation.md#suppressing-specific-agent-instrumentation

Comment: `-Dotel.instrumentation.quartz.enabled` this one disables only job execution traces, but not `jdbc`. `otel.javaagent.exclude-classes` I tried this, but it's definitely hard to identify which class of quartz I need to put here to suppress the jdbc calls.

Comment: I've never used Quartz, so I can't say in detail, but maybe you could look trough the instrumentation itself and check which quartz classes are being used: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/tree/cd528e98fbbaa9bf6e48351d908d43e28a6e0073/instrumentation/quartz-2.0/library/src/main/java/io/opentelemetry/instrumentation/quartz/v2_0

Answer (score 0):

**Open Telemetry**

You can suppress agent instrumentation of specific libraries by using -Dotel.instrumentation.[name].enabled=false (or using the equivalent environment variable OTEL_INSTRUMENTATION_[NAME]_ENABLED) where name (NAME) is the corresponding instrumentation name.

https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/java/automatic/agent-config/#suppressing-specific-agent-instrumentation

**Azure Insigths + Open Telemetry**

For those who are using Azure Insights, the configuration is not the same.

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-monitor/app/java-standalone-config.md#suppress-specific-auto-collected-telemetry